# OAuth 2 access token, pass by query or session

Tags: http, oauth, session

I searched through similar questions but none seem to answer this particular concern:

Assuming I am building a simple oauth user login system, when the oauth flow is done, **should I pass the obtained access token through `GET` query**, such as `/login/provider?access_token=xxxx` (assuming HTTPS), **or should I store it in the session and delete it when my REST api call are done** (assuming HTTPS + Signed cookies)

From what I can see: session approach doesn't expose token to even the user himself, and prevent logfile from recording `?access_token=xxxx`, appear to be the safer bet.

**Are there reasons for choosing GET query? Does my argument apply to OAuth 1 token and secret as well?**